# Need to extract substring from a string in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I have problem extracting date which is represented with in(mar2017) where data is varchar. I need to extract text with in '(' ')' excluding '(' ')'  and need to convert the extracted date into 2 columns and output should be like the below example:
ouput_column should be:

```
startdate           enddate
01-mar-2017        30-mar-2017
```

where the input data is like below example:

```
input_column:
(mar-17)diesel charges for the mention office
(nov2016)diesel charges for the mention office
(mar-2015 to nov-2015)diesel charges for the mention office
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Look into [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) and [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) functions.

Comment: In addition to what @ZLK mentioned, consider `convert` to extract the date as a date type. You'll have to think about how you want to handle the days though.

Comment: till now i manage to extract date using below code: select left(substring(column_name,charindex('('column_name)+1,100),charindex(')',column_name)-2) as start_date from main_table. but it is not extracting accurately.

Comment: @sebastiaan regarding handling of day i am considering first day of the month for starting date and last day of the month for enddate column

Comment: Getting the data between `(` and `)` is the easy part. Parsing it to a couple of dates is going to be much harder.

Comment: @srikrishna can you demonstrate what you have so far? If you have the appropriate permissions, defining a function might help you greatly. Regarding the first/last day problem: Once you have a date at day 1, add 1 month and subtract 1 day to obtain the last day. See `dateadd`.

Comment: @ sebastiaan i able to extract date (mar-17) part in the string , but the there are many patterns in data for example ( JULY-16 TO OCT-16 )  , Iin the above example while extracting i need only  "16" but while extracting i am getting 16 rather i get 16 to oct especially in this pattern of data..

Comment: @sebastiaan ,can you help in extracting only 16 part from the above example , how can i stop extracting the character when it find alphabet character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read this question and try a bit.

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE 
(
   Description nvarchar(200)
)
INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES ('(mar-17)diesel charges for the mention office'), ('(nov2016)diesel charges for the mention office'), 
('(mar-2015 to july-2015)diesel charges for the mention office'), ('(july-2015 to nov-2015)diesel charges for the mention office to')

---- Extract start date, end date from string
; WITH temps AS 
(
   SELECT sd.Description, 
     CASE 
         WHEN CharIndex('to', sd.Description, 1) = 0 OR CharIndex('to', sd.Description, 1) > CharIndex(')', sd.Description, 1)
                THEN SUBSTRing (sd.Description, CharIndex('(', sd.Description, 1) + 1, CharIndex(')', sd.Description, 1) - CharIndex('(', sd.Description, 1) - 1)
         ELSE SUBSTRing (sd.Description, CharIndex('(', sd.Description, 1) + 1, CharIndex('to', sd.Description, 1) - CharIndex('(', sd.Description, 1) - 1)       
     END AS StartDate,
     CASE 
         WHEN CharIndex('to', sd.Description, 1) = 0 OR CharIndex('to', sd.Description, 1) > CharIndex(')', sd.Description, 1)
                THEN SUBSTRing (sd.Description, CharIndex('(', sd.Description, 1) + 1, CharIndex(')', sd.Description, 1) - CharIndex('(', sd.Description, 1) - 1)
         ELSE SUBSTRing (sd.Description, CharIndex('to', sd.Description, 1) + 3, CharIndex(')', sd.Description, 1) - CharIndex('to', sd.Description, 1) - 3)          
     END AS EndDate
FROM @SampleData sd
)
---- Extract string to get month - year
, tempMonthYear as 
(
      SELECT 
      *,
      LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(Substring(t.StartDate,1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.StartDate) - 1),'-',''))) AS StartMonth,
      CASE 
            WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(Substring(t.StartDate, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.StartDate), len(t.StartDate) -PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.StartDate) + 1 )))) = 2
                THEN  '20' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Substring(t.StartDate, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.StartDate), len(t.StartDate) -PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.StartDate) + 1 ))) 
            ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(Substring(t.StartDate, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.StartDate), len(t.StartDate) -PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.StartDate) + 1 ))) 
      END AS StartYear,
      LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(Substring(t.EndDate,1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.EndDate) - 1),'-',''))) AS EndMonth,
      CASE 
            WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(Substring(t.EndDate, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.EndDate), len(t.EndDate) -PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.EndDate) + 1 )))) = 2
                THEN  '20' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Substring(t.EndDate, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.EndDate), len(t.EndDate) -PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.EndDate) + 1 ))) 
            ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(Substring(t.EndDate, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.EndDate), len(t.EndDate) -PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',t.EndDate) + 1 ))) 
      END AS EndYear
FROM temps t
)
-- Get first day, last day of month
SELECT  tmy.Description, FORMAT(CAST(CONCAT('01-', tmy.StartMonth, '-', tmy.StartYear) AS datetime),'dd-MMM-yyyy')  AS StartDate,
      FORMAT(EOMONTH(cast(CONCAT('01-', tmy.EndMonth, '-', tmy.EndYear) AS datetime)), 'dd-MMM-yyyy') AS EndDate
FROM tempMonthYear tmy
```

Demo link: [rextester](http://rextester.com/FJMHD94969)

Comment: ,can please share output of your query, thanks in advance

Comment: Vote and mark as an answer if it's what you need. It means "thank" here .